# Why does aggregate-initializing a non-type template parameter with a placeholder for a deduced class type fail to compile?

Tags: c++, language-lawyer, metaprogramming, c++20

Consider the following code:

```
struct Base_string { char data[1 << 5]; };

template<typename Base>
struct Derived: Base { };

Derived(char const*) -> Derived<Base_string>;

template<Derived>
struct S { };

S<{"Test"}> s; // Error
```

The last line, in which `S` is instantiated, does not compile. I expected it to work, because [[temp.arg.nontype#1]](http://eel.is/c++draft/temp.arg.nontype#1) states that:

> If the type T of a template-parameter contains [...] a placeholder for a deduced class type, the type of the parameter is the type deduced for the variable x in the invented declaration `T x = template-argument;`

In my case, this invented declaration would look like this: `Derived x = {"Test"};`, and actually declaring a variable like this in the program produces no errors - the type is deduced correctly.
Also, I think the problem isn't in the aggregate-initialization syntax itself - changing the definition of the template `S` to:

```
template<Base_string>
struct S { };
```

and instantiating it the same way (`S<{"Test"}> s;`) produces no errors.

I know that I could simply specify the type explicitly, like so: `S<Derived{"Test"}> s;`, but I'm not looking for a work-around, I want to understand why deduction fails here.

Comment: As noted in CWG2450, braced-init-list is not even allowed to be a template-argument.

Comment: @LanguageLawyer As I mentioned in the question, replacing `Derived` with `Base_string` in the definition of the template `S` does compile, even with the braced-init-list as an argument. Does that mean it's some kind of non-standard extension of GCC?

Comment: @Ice1357 https://www.py4u.net/discuss/127116 -- it appears so.  It is a defect in the C++ grammar that gcc did not obey; but they didn't get everything working perfectly.